# Plotting two ranges on one colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

Is it possible to get one colorbar to have two ranges?

Basically I have two plots (created separatly and pasted into a blank image).

They use the same colormap (hot), but the color is over a different range due to the nature of the data in each plot. Basically on the left side of the colorbar I would like the range to be 0-1 and the right to be 0.75 -1.

The colorbar could be created with one plot, or a completely figure. I would like to plot a colorbar.

I currently know how to move the ticks from right to left or the colorbar orientation. However, I can't seem to put the ticks on both sides.

This is the code that I use to plot the ticks on the left of the colorbar rather than the default right, but I can't seem to put them on both sides.

```
    cb = plt.colorbar(sm)
    cb.ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
```

Answer (score 7):

Basically, you can use `twinx` to create another Y-axis, but when I try it to the colobar axe, the aspect setting cause some problem, so I use `set_position()` to change the width of the two axes, here is the code:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(10, 10)
pl.imshow(a)
cb = pl.colorbar(pad=0.1)

l, b, w, h = cb.ax.get_position().bounds
cb.ax.set_aspect("auto")
w = 0.05
ax2 =pl.twinx(ax=cb.ax)
cb.ax.set_position([l, b, w, h])
ax2.set_position([l, b, w, h])
cb.ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
ax2.set_ylim(-10, 10)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: I've some issues with the horizontal oriented colorbar with two ranges, please consider looking to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053551/two-ranges-on-a-horizontal-oriented-colorbar-ticks-are-floating-away-from-colo