# Two ranges on a horizontal oriented colorbar ticks are 'floating away' from colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372509/plotting-two-ranges-on-one-colorbar) I can plot two ranges on a vertical oriented colorbar. Consequently I would like to try to do the same for a horizontal oriented colorbar. This works, but partly. First the code:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(10, 10)

pl.imshow(a)
cb = pl.colorbar(pad=0.1, orientation='horizontal')

l, b, w, h = cb.ax.get_position().bounds
cb.ax.set_aspect("auto")

ax2 =pl.twiny(ax=cb.ax)
cb.ax.set_position([l, b, w, h])
ax2.set_position([l, b, w, h])
cb.ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
ax2.set_ylim(-10, 10)
tight_layout()
```

Then the output:

[image]

This seems to be OK, but the ticks both on the top and the bottom are floating on a certain distance of the colorbar and the height of the colorbar is very small. By increasing the height the ticks become even more apart from the colorbar.

Any suggestions how to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the following changes (see the comments in the code):

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(10, 10)
pl.imshow(a)
cb = pl.colorbar(pad=0.1,  orientation='horizontal')

l, b, w, h = cb.ax.get_position().bounds
print l, b, w, h
cb.ax.set_aspect("auto")
#w = 0.05            # width of the colorbar (from the vertical example)
h = 0.05             # height of the colorbar
ax2 = pl.twiny(ax=cb.ax)
cb.ax.set_position([l, b, w, h])
ax2.set_position([l, b, w, h])
cb.ax.set_xlim(0, 1) # you are now dealing with an horizontal colorbar
                     # so you should define the x lim, not the y lim
ax2.set_xlim(-10, 10)
pl.show()
```

you generate this image:
[image]